# Obtaining the amount of time spent above a threshold value from time series data

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table like this:

```
`sensor` int(11)
`reading` decimal(5,2)
`timestamp` datetime
```

that is representing temperature data and logging an entry whenever a value changes, how would I go about finding the amount of time recorded above a given value?

So there may be a bunch of readings from, say, 16 up to 30, the requirement would be to find the amount of time spent above 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two solutions**

I propose two solutions:

- one query, but I don't know if it is very efficient with a lot of data, because of the subquery;
- one function.

**Schema**

I tested the query and the function with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `temperature` (
    `sensor` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
    `reading` decimal(5, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sensor`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And some data:

```
1;2014-09-18 17:00:00;15.0
1;2014-09-18 18:00:00;16.0
1;2014-09-18 19:00:00;15.0
```

**Solution 1: a query**

```
SELECT SUM(elapsed_time)
FROM (
    SELECT
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP((
            SELECT MIN(t2.timestamp)
            FROM temperature t2
            WHERE t1.sensor = t2.sensor AND t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
        )) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.timestamp))
        AS elapsed_time
    FROM temperature t1
    WHERE t1.sensor = 1 AND t1.reading >= 16.0
) a;
```

**Solution 2: a function**

The function returns the amount of time above a value in seconds for a sensor.

It initializes the amount of time to 0. It then read all readings of the desired sensor. If the temperature is above your requirement, it adds the amount of time to go until the next reading to the sum. At last, it returns the amount of time above your requirement for the sensor.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getTotalTimeAbove;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getTotalTimeAbove(sensor_id INTEGER, above DECIMAL(5, 2))
    RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE curr_time DATETIME;
    DECLARE next_time DATETIME;
    DECLARE curr_reading INTEGER;
    DECLARE next_reading INTEGER;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT `timestamp`, `reading`
        FROM `temperature`
        WHERE `sensor` = sensor_id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO next_time, next_reading;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        IF (curr_reading >= above) THEN
            SET sum = sum + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(next_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curr_time));
        END IF;
        SET curr_time = next_time;
        SET curr_reading = next_reading;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    RETURN sum;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The query and its result:

```
> SELECT getTotalTimeAbove(1, 16.0);
3600
```

**Bonus**

You can have the total amount of recorded time for a sensor with this query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(`timestamp`)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(`timestamp`))
FROM `temperature`
WHERE `sensor` = 1
```